# Problem for returning the maximum value of knapsack

Tags: python, algorithm, knapsack-problem

```
#to avoid calculating those items which violates the terms and to only output , the ansewer satisfying the conditions , with the maximum weigth
def knapsack(w_list,v_list,i,i_w_1,v_w_1,w_cap):
    counter = True
    highest_value = None
    if(i_w_1 + w_list[i] <= w_cap): #this is case when there is no problem
        i_w_2 = i_w_1               #this is basically the evaluation part of the weights of new branch
        v_w_2 = v_w_1
        i_w_1 += w_list[i]
        v_w_1 += v_list[i]
        if(i == len(w_list) - 1):
            print(i_w_1,v_w_1)
            print(i_w_2,v_w_2)
            max_value =  max(v_w_1,v_w_2)
            if counter or highest_value <= max_value:
                counter = False
                highest_value = max_value
                return highest_value
        highest_value = knapsack(w_list,v_list,i+1,i_w_1,v_w_1,w_cap)
        highest_value = knapsack(w_list,v_list,i+1,i_w_2,v_w_2,w_cap)

    elif(i_w_1 + w_list[i] > w_cap):#in this case we have to check which to evaluate and which to not
        if(i_w_1 <= w_cap): #this is basically the evaluation part of the weight of new branch
            i_w_2 = i_w_1
            v_w_2 = v_w_1
        if(i == len(w_list) - 1):
            print(i_w_2,v_w_2)
            return
        knapsack(w_list,v_list,i+1,i_w_2,v_w_2,w_cap)
    return highest_value

w_list =  [1,2]
v_list = [10,20]
i = 0
i_w_1 = 0
v_w_1 = 0 #let us suppose the initial value associated with our weights be zero
w_cap = 3
highest_value = knapsack(w_list,v_list,i,i_w_1,v_w_1,w_cap)
print(highest_value)
```

I am simply printing all the weight combinations of the given weight capacity and i am returning the maximum possible value , but what is happening here ,that for one brach it returns maximum and as soon as the function call pops out from stack it returns None ,and then the maximum  of second branch is calculated and at end it is returning that only , i want to calculate the highest value by comparing all the branches
One way of doing this is by passing a global_var initialized to a value and then updating it and comparing , it , but how to do this by initializing a local inside function
I see people on this community sometimes , show no sort of compassion for problem faced by beginners , i tried every other way but when i was not able to get a answer , i am posting it here

Comment: In the `if` branch, you call `knapsack()` recursively twice, assigning the result to `highest_value` each time, so the first call's result is forgotten. In the `else` branch, you call `knapsack()` recursively but don't even save the return value.

Comment: yes , i modified that , and i  am collecting value , but still it is printing the same , as the result of first call is forgotten   , but i want to collect a result for first call , and then compare that with each subsequent calls and update the value if needed

Comment: i just ignored collecting the value , as it was not needed for the inputs given , but still i am not able to compare and update the highest_value

Comment: please someone help in correcting the code